# Socket.io alternatives for real time communication applications

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I have built a multiplayer game with real time leader board. The game is in PHP(Backend) + Flex(Front end).
I have used socket.io for real time communication with a node.js server. But I am facing a lot of problem with respect to proxy settings on my client network configuration. Most of the time my application doesn't communicate with my node(socket) server. It is not able to establish a connection because of proxy configurations.

What alternatives can I go with? I tried to search a lot for alternatives. I came across services like pusher and pubnub, but those are little expensive. Have anyone tried Amazon SNS, is it suitable for this?

Thanks!

Comment: the role of the Node.js server is unclear from the question. if you have problems communicating between your PHP backend and Node.js server you can use Redis's pub/sub functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you cannot connect through proxies, is because socket.io is using web sockets.  See [Socket.io and firewall Software](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software) (that page also includes a link to test websocket connectivity). There are a number of ways you can mitigate this problem:

1. Use secure websockets (wss://)
   But this does also not guarantee for 100% that it will work.
2. Use one of the fallback mechanisms of socket.io: Flash, Ajax, iFrame, JSONP, ...
   For more information, see [Configuring Socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO).

Answer (score 0):

There is SocketCluster: https://github.com/topcloud/socketcluster
It runs on multiple CPU cores and it's good with error-handling (workers auto-respawn). It has no identified memory leaks (just make sure you use latest version of Node.js).